# Given a partial order $R$ on the set $A$, prove that there exists a total order $\leq$ on $A$ such that $R \subseteq {\le}$

Tags: order-theory

> Let $A$ be a finite set, and $\langle A,R\rangle $ be partially ordered.
>
> $\textbf{Prove}$ that there exists a total order $\leq$ over $A$ such that $R \subseteq {\le}$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ Define $B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ by
$B = \{ k \in \mathbb{N}\mid$ there is a partial order $S$ on $A$ such that $ R \subseteq S$ and $|S| = k   \}$.

Now, I tried to prove that $B \neq \emptyset$ and Bounded.
I thought about using the maximum principle (the opposite of the Well-ordering principle).

Comment: By bounded you mean bounded above? That is trivial, since $A$ is finite, so how is this going to help? That $B\ne\emptyset$ is also trivial, since $|R|\in B$. There is no "opposite" of the well-ordering principle, can you say more precisely what you mean? Also, can you explain better what your strategy is, that is, what is it you attempt to accomplish by looking at $B$?

Comment: Let $A$ be a finite set.

Maximum Principle - $\exists n_{0}\in A$ such that $ n\leq n_{0}$ for all $n\in A$

Answer (score 1):

I can’t follow your description of what you’re trying to do, I’m afraid. One straightforward approach is to prove the result by induction on $|A|$. If you know the result for sets of cardinality $n$, and $|A|=n+1$, fix $a_0\in A$, extend the restriction of $R$ to $A\setminus\{a_0\}$ to a linear order on $A\setminus\{a_0\}$, and then show that it’s always possible to insert $a_0$ into this linear order to get a linear extension of $R$.

**Added:** In more detail, $P(n)$ is the statement that if $\langle A,R\rangle$ is a partial order, and $|A|=n$, then there is a linear order $L$ on $A$ such that $R\subseteq L$. This is trivial for $n=1$. The induction argument is to assume that $P(n)$ is true and show that $P(n+1)$ is true. To do this, start with a partial order $\langle A,R\rangle$ such that $|A|=n+1$. Pick any $a_0\in A$, let $A_0=A\setminus\{a_0\}$, and let $R_0=R\cap(A_0\times A_0)$. Then $\langle A_0,R_0\rangle$ is a partial order, and $|A_0|=n$, so by the induction hypothesis there is a linear order $L_0$ on $A_0$ such that $R_0\subseteq L_0$. Now show that it is possible to insert $a_0$ into the linear order $L_0$ to get a linear order $L$ of all of $A$ such that $R\subseteq L$.

Comment: Im trying to understand this,Can you explain it more clear ?
Thanks.

Comment: @Nir: Can you be more specific about what parts you don’t understand?

Comment: The way you use the induction to prove that.

Comment: @Nir: I added a lot of detail to the answer. I really don’t want to say much more than that, because that would be doing the entire problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_0,y_0$ are not comparable. Let $X=\{x\in A:xRx_0\}$ and $Y=\{x\in A:y_0Rx\}$. Let $\le$ be the result of adding to the partial order $R$ all pairs $(x,y)$ where $x\in X,y\in Y$. We claim that $\le$ is also a partial order.

Note that $X\cap Y=\emptyset$, for if $x\in X\cap Y$, then $xRx_0$ and $y_0Rx$, so by transitivity $y_0Rx_0$, contradicting the fact that $y_0,x_0$ are not comparable. Moreover, if $x\in X,y\in Y$ we cannot have $yRx$ for then $y_0RyRxRx_0$, so $y_0Rx_0$, again contradicting the fact that $x_0,y_0$ are not comparable.

$\le$ is obviously reflexive. Suppose $x\le y\le x$. If $x\ne y$, then we must have $x\in X,y\in Y$ (or we would not have $x\le y$). So we must have $x\notin Y$, so $y\le x$ implies $yRx$. But $xRx_0$, so by transitivity of $R$ we have $yRx_0$ and hence $y\in X$. Contradiction. So $xRy$. Similarly, we get $yRx$, so $x=y$. Hence $\le$ is also antisymmetric.

Finally, suppose $x\le y\le z$. There are three cases:

(1) $xRy$ is false. So $x\in X,y\in Y$. Then $y\notin X$, so $y\le z$ implies $yRz$. But $y\in Y$, so $z\in Y$. But $z\in X,z\in Y$ implies $x\le z$.

(2) $xRyRz$. Then $xRz$ and so $x\le z$.

(3) $xRy$ and $y\in X,z\in Y$. But $xRy,y\in X$ implies $x\in X$. Now $x\in X,z\in Y$ implies $x\le z$.

So $\le$ is partial order. But $A$ is finite, so there are only finitely many pairs of elements. Hence repeating this process a finite number of times we get a total order which extends $R$.

Comment: I dont understand the last part - "Hence repeating this process a finite number of times we get a total order which extends $R$".